# To call a page on click of an ActionLink in the same View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.actionlink

i am developing an application in MVC3..
I have several links on the leftside and on click of the link the page should be displayed on the right side
I have made a table.
in the First Column the links are displayed like this:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.HobbyName, "Hobbies")</li>
}
```

and in the second column i need to display information about the links when it is clicked but i am not understanding hw shud i do that..
Like What shud i write in the Controller to fetch those views in this column.
Please Help me

Comment: Suggest you check out and learn from these videos on the right hand side: http://asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax.ActionLink instead of Html.Actionlink and set update target id in Ajax Options to the div you want to update. Example

```
<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<li>
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.HobbyName, "Hobbies",
             new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divHobyList" })
</li>
}
</ul>

<div id="divHobyList">
here will load hobbies
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanx 4 replying i want a new url to be loaded inside the new column so if my item.HobbyName contains an url will dat be loaded dynamically? and do i hve to write an ajax for it in my view.Also i ll be using Iframe to show the content.